How to make two slab geoms share thickness scale with faceting?
I’ve been using ggdist along with distributional and
posterior to visualize Bayesian model results.
I’m struggling with a seemingly simple problem in ggdist, however.
I’m trying to plot density histograms of posterior samples overlaid with
analytical prior PDFs in a faceted layout, with one parameter per panel.
I can’t figure out how to make the y-axis (density) scales (1)
commensurate between slab geoms within a panel, so the prior and
posterior have the same integral, and also (2) free to vary across
panels. Consider a toy example:
# setup
library(dplyr)
library(distributional)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdist)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 16))

# posterior draws
samples <- data.frame(parameter = factor(rep(letters[1:2], 1000)),
                      value = rnorm(2000, mean = 0, sd = c(1,100)))
                      
# prior PDFs using distributional
pdfs <- data.frame(parameter = factor(letters[1:2]),
                   pdf = c(dist_normal(0,2), dist_normal(0,200)))

What I want is the equivalent of this base plot:
fx <- function(x, pdf) unlist(density(pdf, x))

par(mfcol = c(1,2), mar = c(3,2,4,2), oma = c(2,2,0,0))
for(i in levels(samples$parameter)) {
  hist(samples$value[samples$parameter == i], prob = TRUE, 
       xlab = "", ylab = "", main = i, las = 1)
  curve(fx(x, pdfs$pdf[pdfs$parameter == i]), lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
}
mtext(c("value","density"), side = c(1,2), outer = TRUE, line = c(0,1), cex = 1.3)


Here is my first attempt with ggdist:
samples %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  stat_slab(aes(x = value), density = "histogram", normalize = "panels") +
  stat_slab(data = pdfs, aes(xdist = pdf), normalize = "panels", 
            col = "black", fill = NA) +
  facet_wrap(vars(parameter), scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "value", y = "density", title = "normalize = 'panels'", 
       subtitle = "equalizes max densities, not integrals")


This normalizes the maximum thicknesses of the prior and posterior
slabs, independently, within each panel. Thus the plotted histogram
and PDF are not comparable; they don’t have the same integral. From
reading the doc and vignette, I thought scale_thickness_shared() would resolve this
issue, and it does work as expected when a single parameter is plotted.
But when faceting, this causes the free y-axis scales to be ignored, as if I had changed normalize = "panels" to "none":
samples %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  stat_slab(aes(x = value), density = "histogram") +
  stat_slab(data = pdfs, aes(xdist = pdf), col = "black", fill = NA) +
  scale_thickness_shared() +
  facet_wrap(vars(parameter), scales = "free") +
  labs(x = "value", y = "density", title = "scale_thickness_shared()",
       subtitle = "equalizes integrals, but density scales are no longer free")


I’ve tried alternative normalize settings and the renormalize
argument to scale_thickness_shared() to no avail. Ideally I would
prefer the heights of the density histogram and the PDF to be the actual
numerical densities, as in the base graphics version. I don’t fully
understand how the slab thickness aesthetic works, but I gather this
isn’t possible because thickness is somehow independent of, and
rescaled relative to, the y-axis scale. That’s not a deal-breaker
since the absolute density values are meaningless for my purposes, but I do
need the integrals of the two slabs to be the same within each panel and
the scales to be free across panels.
I’m probably missing something obvious. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

The figures are now directly visible. It is very hard to follow your post. It is more likely to receive an answer if the question is compact, e.g. move code sections in front of plots and reduce your paragraphs.

@Friede, thanks for making the figures visible (if that was you). They were in fact originally after the code chunks, but I moved them to links after SO prevented me from posting inline images; I have now restored their positions. Is that the reason you found my post unclear, or is there something else?
